# Can't Delete Empty S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an S3 bucket that is 100% empty.  Versioning was never enabled on the bucket.  However, I still cannot remove the bucket.  I have tried via the Console and the CLI tool.  On the console it just says "Error" with no error message.  From the cli and api it tells me: "An error occurred (BucketNotEmpty) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty".  I have tried all of the following:

`aws s3 rb s3://<bucket_name> --force` -> BucketNotEmpty

`aws s3 rm s3://<bucket_name> --recursive` -> No output (because it's already empty)

`aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket <bucket_name>` -> No output (because versioning was never enabled)

`aws s3api list-multipart-uploads --bucket <bucket_name>` -> No outputs

`aws s3api list-objects --delimiter=/ --prefix= --bucket <bucket_name>` -> No Output (because it's empty)

- It has no dependencies (it's not used by cloudfront or anything else that I'm aware of).
- The bucket has been empty for approximately 5 days.
- I was able to delete another very similar bucket with the same IAM user.  Additionally my IAM user has Admin access.

Comment: How long has it been empty?

Comment: It's been empty for about five days @Alden

Comment: I would open a ticket with AWS support

Comment: I'll bet it isn't *really* empty. `aws s3api list-multipart-uploads` will show any abandoned multipart uploads that were never canceled. They time out... never, unless you configure a timeout in bucket lifecycle policy. Check this?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I checked and there are no multi-part uploads

Comment: Have you tried the `Empty Bucket` option (in the context menu on the bucket) from the AWS Management Console before using `$ aws s3 rb s3://bucket-name --force`?

Comment: While not related to the error message, check permissions on the bucket. For example, remove any bucket policy. Also, test whether you can delete a different bucket to confirm that your general permissions are okay.

Comment: Also, did you verify that `aws s3api list-objects --delimiter=/ --prefix=` shows nothing?  It seems unexpected that S3 would have a bug like this.

Comment: @KhalidT. I tried the `Empty Bucket` from the console and it succeeded but I still cannot remove the bucket.
@JohnRotenstein There are no bucket policies, tags, anything.  I removed absolutely everything I could.  As far as I know there is nothing attached to the bucket nor referencing the bucket.
@Michael-sqlbot I tried that too.  No luck.  I'm assuming this is an error between the chair and keyboard but I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @TimMartin is the bucket being hosted as a static website or is it being associated with a Route53 domain?

Comment: @PrestonM No.  As far as I know, there are absolutely no references to the bucket elsewhere in S3

Comment: For anyone interested, I tried deleting the bucket today just for the sake of it (we ended up circumventing this completely).  Somehow, it magically worked.  I've made no changes related to this bucket so I'm beginning to think there was some underlying bug.

Answer (score 160):

I was facing this same problem. I was able to fix the issue by going into the bucket and deleting the "Bucket Policy" for the bucket. After that, deleting the bucket worked correctly.

I did this through the AWS console, for an S3 bucket created by Elastic Beanstalk (ie elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-861587641234). I imagine the creation script includes a policy to prevent people from accidentally deleting the bucket.

Comment: In my case, I had `DeletionPolicy` set to `Retain` for `BucketPolicy`, which caused the bucket to not delete.

Comment: I changed the deletion policy found under Bucket Policy tab inside the bucket details to "allow" from "deny". It changed the access status of the bucket to "Public". After that I was able to delete it. So, this technique works. Kudos.

Comment: AWS documentation regarding this topic and deleting your S3 Buckets created by EB here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.S3.html

Comment: @bkunzi01 - searched extensively for a solution and in the end, SO comment points me to the correct AWS documentation, says a lot about AWS documentation usability.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue and was able to delete the bucket after waiting overnight. 
It's a pretty weak solution but may save you and other some time from pounding on it.

If it's still not deleting after all the actions in the comments there are some things that only AWS support can fix properly. Again a weak answer but register a ticket with AWS support and then post their response here as an answer for others.

Comment: Thanks. I'm faced with the same situation and was wondering if I should just try again tomorrow. This is a poor experience and AWS part.

Comment: @JoseQuijada you just have to wait - frankly, I'm surprised this is still an issue.

Answer (score 8):

This is what had worked for me. I didn't have versioning enabled on the bucket. When you delete an object from s3 bucket, it puts a 'delete marker' on that object and hides it from the listing. When you click 'show' version button you will see your deleted objects with the delete marker. Select this object (with delete marker) and delete again. This is a permanent delete. Now your object is really gone and your bucket is really empty. After this I was able to delete my bucket.

I guess, versioning=true only means that s3 will create versions of the object if you upload with the same name.

Answer (score 8):

To delete an Elastic Beanstalk storage bucket (console)

```
1. Open the Amazon S3 Management Console
2. Select the Elastic Beanstalk storage bucket.
3. Choose Properties.
4. Choose Permissions.
5. Choose Edit Bucket Policy - Allow to delete and make it public.
6. Save.
7. Choose Actions and then choose Delete Bucket.
8, Type the name of the bucket and then choose Delete.
```

Answer (score 4):

For users who are facing similar issue.
I tried @Federico solution still no success. There was an other option "Empty" next to delete.

[image]

So I emptied the bucket first and then tried delete, it worked.

Comment: This worked for me as well. But isn't it strange that we need to empty the bucket even when there are no files in it.

Comment: @RBT yes thats what I thought earlier, I guess its a way to delete hidden references that are associated for that bucket.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing an issue with deleting the Elastic Beanstalk storage bucket.
Follow the below steps:

```
1. Select the Elastic Beanstalk storage bucket.
2. Choose Permissions.
3. Delete the bucket policy
4. Save.
```

If your bucket is empty, you can delete the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

Using aws cli :

```
# delete contents of a bucket
aws s3api delete-objects --bucket nameOfYourBucket --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket nameOfYourBucket --query='{Objects: Versions[].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')"

# delete older version files from bucket
aws s3api delete-objects --bucket nameOfYourBucket --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket nameOfYourBucket --query='{Objects: DeleteMarkers[].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')"
```

And then you can delete the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes after attempting to delete a bucket, it's not actually deleted, but the permissions are lost.

In my case, I went to the "permissions" tab, re-granted permissions to myself, and was then able to remove it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and there was not a policy, so added permission for the email I was logged in with and saved. After granting myself permission I was able to delete the bucket. I also had another bucket that had a policy, so I delete the policy and was able to delete that bucket as well.

Comment: I just selected the bucket, went to the policies tab and deleted the policy. That let me delete the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by checking the bucket permissions and changing `"Effect"` key from `"Deny"` to `"Allow"`. Make sure you have `"s3:DeleteBucket"` permission included.

Answer (score 0):

i made the s3 bucket permission to public, and gave access to everyone. Then i was able to delete the Bucket from the AWS console.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the AWS Console to perform deletion of the bucket.

had the same problem and I tried all the above solutions and not worked for me then I figured out another way.
My bucket was used by ElasticBean and whenever I deleted the bucket the ElasticBean created one automatically. I then deleted the ElasticBean service and tried to delete the bucket again but not worked again this time, the bucket was empty but was not allowing to delete.
I tried to change permissions but the bucket was still there.

Finally I deleted the bucket policy and came back and deleted the bucket and it was gone.
 Problem solved

Answer (score -5):

I tried to look at many of the solutions mentioned. The only thing that worked for me is deleting it through Cyberduck (I neither work for nor am promoting Cyberduck, i genuinely used it and it worked). Here are the steps of what I did:

1 - Download and install Cyberduck.

2 - Click on Open Connection

3 - Select Amazon S3 from the dropdown (default would be FTP)

4 - Enter your access key ID and secret Access key (if you dont have one then you need to create one on your s3 bucket through IAM on AWS)

5 - You will see a list your S3 buckets. Select the file or folder or bucket you want to delete, right click and delete. Even files with 0kb show up here and can be deleted.

Hope this helps