# What is the trick to delete an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to delete a S3 bucket in AWS via the webpage but nothing happens -- no error message, no popup, nothing. The delete screen has a standard "Type the name of the bucket to confirm deletion" message and I did type it (yes, I'm 100% sure I spelled it correctly, I've tried copy-paste, etc) but when I hit the Confirm button nothing happens. No error message, and the delete screen doesn't go away, etc. Nothing happens.

On many guis, the "Confirm" button would be grayed out or change color once you successfully type the thing to be deleted, but that's not happening here -- the button appears clickable even before I type anything; but clicking it doesn't do anything either before I type my bucket or after.

Here's a screenshot (I scribbled out part of the name because that has my personal info; but I'm sure I'm typing it correctly). Is there a trick I have to do to delete this?
[image]

UPDATE: I tried creating a new different bucket and then was able to delete that with no problem. But I still can't delete this one. I think maybe this bucket is somehow in-use or orphaned or something but I can't find any trace of it being used anywhere else in the AWS console and there's no error message (or any action at all) when I click the confirm button, so I don't know why AWS is refusing to do anything. How can I 100% force nuke this bucket away?

FURTHER UPDATE: Clicking on that bucket on the webpage says "Error Data not found" which makes me think something got orphaned here. But the bucket is still showing up, so how can I force delete it?

[image]

Comment: You may get more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811971/cant-delete-empty-s3-bucket

Comment: Open the Network Tab and see if there are any failed request.

Comment: Come back in a few hours and I suspect you'll find the bucket is gone.

Comment: I suspect you don't have permission to delete this bucket and the S3 console is not showing this failure to you. It may have an S3 policy that was applied incorrectly and now prevents you deleting it. Try `aws s3 rb s3://bucketname` using the awcli. What happens?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your bucket is empty and no policy is associated with it.

Also, This is what had worked for me. I didn't have versioning enabled on the bucket. When you delete an object from the s3 bucket, it puts a 'delete marker' on that object and hides it from the listing. When you click the 'show' version button you will see your deleted objects with the delete marker. Select this object (with delete marker) and delete it again. This is a permanent delete. Now your object is really gone and your bucket is really empty. After this, I was able to delete my bucket.

I guess, versioning=true only means that s3 will create versions of the object if you upload with the same name.

Comment: I tried to empty the bucket, but it won't let me do that either -- same issue as above where it asks me to type the bucket name and I did, but then nothing happens. Is there any way to force it to delete?

Comment: How do I delete the policy? (Or see if there is a policy? It's not showing me anything on this screen)

Comment: you can find the bucket policy by selecting the bucket then on right side pane, select properties, then permissions then bucket policy.

Selected Bucket -> Properties -> Permissions->Bucket policy

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a delay on Amazon's side. I waited for the next day and then the bucket disappeared on its own. So I guess Amazon's cache just had to refresh or something.